# Why does my non-linear regression system give poor validation results?

Tags: matlab, system, non-linear-regression, system-identification

I am trying to identify a nonlinear system. This system is a differential drive AGV. Somehow the motion equations I found in a paper and the one from Simulinks Mobile Robotics Toolbox don't fit at all to my system. Hence I try to identify my system using step responses.

I have measurements regarding its lateral deviation and its orientation. Since its a differential drive AGV I also have two inputs (RPM right wheel, RPM left wheel).

Somehow, I receive quite okayish accuracy results for my estimation data set but really bad accuracy for my validation data set.

Here is a quick working example of my MATLAB script:

```
% read measurements from CSV
T = readtable("step response\StepResponse.csv");
y_dev = yDev;
theta = theta;
right = rpmRight;
left = rpmLeft;

% create iddata object
y_est = [y_dev theta];
u_est = [right left]; 
data_est = iddata(y_est, u_est, 0.008);

% fit model to data

Orders = [[2, 2; 2, 2], ones(2, 2), 0*ones(2, 2)];
NL = [idGaussianProcess, idWaveletNetwork];
sys = nlarx(data_est, Orders, NL);

compare(data_est, sys)
set(findall(gca, 'Type', 'Line'),'LineWidth',4);
grid on
```

Doing so, I receive an accuracy of 94,77% for the first output channel and 83,61% for the second.
I know that this isn't the best accuracy but right now, I don't know how to improve the accuracy.

Then, I compare another measurement series to my model like following:

```
T = readtable("step response\StepResponse_3.csv");
y_dev = yDev;
theta = theta;
right = rpmRight;
left = rpmLeft;

y_val = [y_dev, theta];
u_val = [right left];
data_val = iddata(y_val, u_val, 0.008);

compare(data_val, sys)
set(findall(gca, 'Type', 'Line'),'LineWidth',4);
grid on
```

On my validation data set i receive -228.3% accuracy on first output channel and -86.21% accuracy for the second output channel.
I expect the system to have a significantly better accuracy on my validation data set.

The estimation data set is monitored for 0 RPM on my right wheel and 410 RPM on my left wheel.
The validation data set is created by using 500 RPM on my right wheel and 0 RPM on my left wheel.

Does anyone of you have an Idea why I get so bad validation results whilst estimation works quite okay?
What can I do to even increase estimation accuracy?

EDIT:
I have to add that I cutted the measurements where my magnetic sensor lost the signal of the magnet stripe.
The loss of the signal leads to a steady part in my lateral deviation followed by a negative shift to the first value measured by the sensor. I'm not quite sure but I guess its quite hard to precisely identify this behaviour.

Comment: for the sake of reproducibility; any chance to use StepResponse.csv ?

Comment: @JohnBG I don't know how to add my files properly, so I added an answer to my question with a snippet of my measurement series.

Answer (score -1):

StepResponse.csv:

```
yDev;theta;rpmRight;rpmLeft
-0.195320397615433;0.416013687849045;0;0
-0.187730833888054;0.413762509822845;0;0
-0.182631373405457;0.412252008914948;0;0
-0.178069859743118;0.410899758338928;0;0
-0.171503901481628;0.408950924873352;0;0
-0.165268868207932;0.407101809978485;0;0
-0.161321550607681;0.405933052301407;0;0
-0.155225679278374;0.404124200344086;0;0
-0.149264469742775;0.402355253696442;0;0
-0.145350128412247;0.401195913553238;0;0
-0.141160175204277;0.39995339512825;0;0
-0.135644510388374;0.398317813873291;0;0
-0.130778059363365;0.396876037120819;0;0
-0.127644300460815;0.395946383476257;0;386
-0.124515369534492;0.395016521215439;0;390
-0.119130745530128;0.393416255712509;0;118
-0.113304913043976;0.385411441326141;34;250
-0.108539871871471;0.369042843580246;65;302
-0.103700838983059;0.352664202451706;0;362
-0.100276537239552;0.341001093387604;28;412
-0.0977251455187798;0.332242369651794;-40;445
-0.0935798585414886;0.307084798812866;2;518
-0.111095115542412;0.271441578865051;43;547
-0.153164371848106;0.22386035323143;0;541
-0.184987649321556;0.170636221766472;0;566
-0.205242112278938;0.130814164876938;-11;568
-0.237443014979362;0.0919957384467125;0;555
-0.302952706813812;0.0353395827114582;-21;586
-0.378104507923126;-0.0237599313259125;0;521
-0.447450786828995;-0.0764745771884918;-69;502
-0.548043847084045;-0.171946212649345;5;521
-0.652697682380676;-0.26395383477211;-16;541
-0.74550724029541;-0.318136960268021;17;528
-0.849703550338745;-0.376023471355438;-57;515
-1.00058722496033;-0.483227133750916;-2;508
-1.14878559112549;-0.598467230796814;-74;469
-1.25823295116425;-0.673773407936096;-43;452
-1.39804780483246;-0.76567941904068;45;427
-1.61588180065155;-0.908254027366638;-36;434
-1.815314412117;-1.03388333320618;63;420
-1.94043135643005;-1.11247134208679;-39;407
-2.12544584274292;-1.2450829744339;-9;410
-2.31702756881714;-1.3878732919693;6;400
-2.45398473739624;-1.4848153591156;-23;396
-2.59367251396179;-1.58124208450317;46;383
-2.80362939834595;-1.72808742523193;1;380
-3.01366114616394;-1.87687051296234;0;395
-3.16009640693665;-1.98009705543518;-47;402
-3.30521559715271;-2.08142280578613;45;405
-3.54095530509949;-2.23827528953552;1;402
-3.79735684394836;-2.40219855308533;-10;366
-3.97825717926025;-2.51305150985718;56;383
-4.24881649017334;-2.68679022789001;-16;373
-4.51508045196533;-2.87191247940063;25;380
-4.67756271362305;-2.99732208251953;-41;378
-4.83472633361816;-3.11807155609131;-7;385
-5.08529233932495;-3.28365206718445;23;383
-5.33794069290161;-3.44995021820068;0;395
-5.54182195663452;-3.61203289031982;0;398
-5.89051532745361;-3.89971518516541;52;394
-6.2713360786438;-4.17912244796753;32;406
-6.61806917190552;-4.37107992172241;56;403
-6.89726877212524;-4.5166916847229;0;407
-7.07831811904907;-4.60471248626709;39;425
-7.26992607116699;-4.70030212402344;0;437
-7.57161331176758;-4.86466312408447;-10;429
-7.8768105506897;-5.0287766456604;10;424
-8.0762939453125;-5.13312768936157;-33;427
-8.27049827575684;-5.23297786712646;0;430
-8.54902362823486;-5.37533664703369;0;426
-8.83362865447998;-5.52331638336182;0;412
-9.0512638092041;-5.62869739532471;0;414
-9.2720193862915;-5.72687005996704;0;407
-9.6021671295166;-5.88321924209595;-2;416
-9.92439842224121;-6.03905200958252;0;407
-10.1358833312988;-6.13861083984375;-47;408
-10.4664421081543;-6.31128454208374;-1;412
-10.7864751815796;-6.48744249343872;-1;413
-10.9836921691895;-6.60140705108643;0;403
-11.1956014633179;-6.72035789489746;0;404
-11.5222473144531;-6.89244985580444;0;412
-11.8427610397339;-7.05986738204956;25;413
-12.0693397521973;-7.17289543151855;0;422
-12.2911357879639;-7.29005718231201;0;420
-12.6069135665894;-7.46352434158325;0;410
-12.9284582138062;-7.63532686233521;0;407
-13.1596584320068;-7.76056671142578;0;408
-13.397403717041;-7.89115047454834;0;411
-13.7465200424194;-8.08006000518799;0;404
-14.1096591949463;-8.27448654174805;0;396
-14.3695392608643;-8.41774559020996;0;401
-14.6017169952393;-8.55542850494385;0;404
-14.964015007019;-8.75742721557617;0;409
-15.3328123092651;-8.96081066131592;10;399
-15.5639848709106;-9.09923458099365;0;411
-15.9141931533813;-9.32032012939453;-44;404
-16.2808265686035;-9.54283714294434;2;412
-16.5403919219971;-9.68263530731201;71;403
-16.7770862579346;-9.81118488311768;1;407
-17.3453941345215;-10.0449819564819;0;411
-18.2846794128418;-10.3194608688354;-23;414
-18.9179382324219;-10.4559297561646;-41;410
-19.2235527038574;-10.5169143676758;0;410
-19.5378513336182;-10.5715484619141;-26;414
-20.0166301727295;-10.6399927139282;-3;401
-20.5004806518555;-10.7030067443848;2;410
-20.8253364562988;-10.740439414978;-37;399
-21.1615219116211;-10.767053604126;50;414
-21.6448860168457;-10.808424949646;-72;406
-22.1361865997314;-10.8456201553345;-39;415
-22.4826507568359;-10.8670530319214;19;411
-22.7961368560791;-10.8910799026489;8;411
-23.244176864624;-10.9187259674072;81;410
-23.6827354431152;-10.9417028427124;-40;406
-23.9858360290527;-10.9511051177979;38;405
-24.438549041748;-10.9637928009033;-8;408
-24.8815803527832;-10.9724645614624;59;422
-25.2135829925537;-10.9659538269043;-51;405
-25.5474014282227;-10.957010269165;27;412
-26.0256462097168;-10.9381971359253;-17;408
-26.5108165740967;-10.9133796691895;13;412
-26.8520126342773;-10.8877716064453;-29;409
-27.2028999328613;-10.8651628494263;-6;411
-27.6900653839111;-10.8377952575684;-14;394
-28.1531181335449;-10.8041687011719;69;416
-28.4510765075684;-10.7819929122925;-18;415
-28.9394493103027;-10.7385063171387;0;410
-29.4443492889404;-10.6842164993286;0;405
-29.7737827301025;-10.6407461166382;0;407
-30.0946865081787;-10.5981311798096;0;412
-30.6306076049805;-10.5235815048218;0;406
-31.1751022338867;-10.4486513137817;0;405
-31.5188941955566;-10.3982200622559;0;397
-32.035572052002;-10.3136215209961;0;409
-32.5309944152832;-10.2328643798828;0;408
-32.8357849121094;-10.1830463409424;0;415
-33.1779747009277;-10.1214427947998;0;410
-34.0459899902344;-9.95829105377197;0;402
-35.0759696960449;-9.76027774810791;0;412
-35.5995178222656;-9.65248680114746;0;404
-35.9266319274902;-9.58287906646729;0;412
-36.248405456543;-9.51430988311768;0;408
-36.7131652832031;-9.41522693634033;0;412
-37.1904525756836;-9.31002044677734;0;405
-37.5353584289551;-9.22960376739502;0;411
-37.8858222961426;-9.14612579345703;0;419
-38.4250602722168;-9.01567935943604;0;404
-38.9590873718262;-8.88425159454346;0;402
-39.3275146484375;-8.78989124298096;0;408
-39.8659324645996;-8.65213108062744;0;415
-40.4053421020508;-8.51192188262939;0;410
-40.7826385498047;-8.41068458557129;0;422
-41.1618576049805;-8.30873203277588;0;412
-41.8210144042969;-8.13139724731445;0;406
-42.4679222106934;-7.95547723770142;0;409
-42.8424797058105;-7.8507399559021;-24;405
-43.3950233459473;-7.69625949859619;14;416
-43.9372329711914;-7.54465007781982;0;414
-44.3031005859375;-7.44124698638916;0;421
-44.7007446289063;-7.3261456489563;0;404
-45.3117485046387;-7.14847898483276;0;418
-45.8883399963379;-6.98144006729126;0;405
-46.2736206054688;-6.86739015579224;0;417
-46.6764335632324;-6.7460355758667;0;410
-47.2988815307617;-6.55711460113525;0;405
-47.9460296630859;-6.35873174667358;0;402
-48.3981666564941;-6.21851825714111;0;399
-48.8458442687988;-6.07954978942871;0;420
-49.5306816101074;-5.86467981338501;0;407
-50.2260208129883;-5.64488887786865;0;420
-50.7057418823242;-5.4919958114624;0;406
-51.4271583557129;-5.261314868927;0;414
-52.1346588134766;-5.03445863723755;0;410
-52.586856842041;-4.88880968093872;0;409
-53.0889167785645;-4.7270188331604;0;410
-54.0201721191406;-4.4267749786377;0;407
-54.868824005127;-4.15295696258545;0;403
-55.2714500427246;-4.02294588088989;0;409
-55.845329284668;-3.83761477470398;0;403
-56.3993682861328;-3.65854167938232;0;409
-56.7585105895996;-3.54236817359924;0;413
-57.5111885070801;-3.29905319213867;-49;403
-58.2477264404297;-3.06086182594299;17;411
-58.5681076049805;-2.95719838142395;0;411
-59.0246505737305;-2.80938816070557;0;412
-59.4627838134766;-2.66751933097839;0;407
-59.7384147644043;-2.57829260826111;0;408
-60.0191535949707;-2.48732852935791;0;413
-60.4339141845703;-2.35290884971619;0;405
-60.8257484436035;-2.2260274887085;0;411
-61.0748710632324;-2.14529776573181;0;401
-61.4390144348145;-2.02727842330933;0;408
-61.789005279541;-1.91392767429352;0;407
-62.0148086547852;-1.84070909023285;0;418
-62.2342338562012;-1.76957488059998;0;408
-62.5546722412109;-1.66567873954773;0;408
-62.8801498413086;-1.56015133857727;0;417
-63.0948829650879;-1.49055874347687;0;412
-63.2916870117188;-1.42672824859619;-43;406
-63.5802459716797;-1.33298778533936;53;407
-63.8583488464355;-1.24278879165649;37;409
-64.03271484375;-1.18639814853668;-28;410
-64.2045364379883;-1.13066756725311;-21;421
-64.4543380737305;-1.04962527751923;-26;402
-64.7114791870117;-0.966202616691589;-5;409
-64.8822631835938;-0.910813748836517;-37;434
-65.1062469482422;-0.838165581226349;-15;407
-65.3225479125977;-0.767989695072174;1;392
-65.4597930908203;-0.723458886146545;0;400
-65.5974578857422;-0.678777039051056;0;401
```

StepResponse_3.csv:

```
yDev;theta;rpmRight;rpmLeft
0.675056159496307;-0.241735234856606;43;0
0.68289589881897;-0.244542598724365;78;0
0.690464317798615;-0.247252762317657;45;0
0.701563894748688;-0.251227468252182;110;0
0.712498664855957;-0.255143105983734;158;41
0.719419777393341;-0.257621496915817;198;8
0.729886591434479;-0.261369556188583;214;0
0.74031925201416;-0.265105426311493;300;2
0.74663907289505;-0.263201177120209;319;72
0.754286348819733;-0.249079063534737;331;7
0.790236830711365;-0.231619268655777;409;19
0.835775911808014;-0.222374185919762;433;47
0.802315354347229;-0.190259456634521;456;48
0.735059916973114;-0.165938198566437;490;1
0.731223344802856;-0.16866660118103;539;2
0.761554479598999;-0.164464130997658;560;48
0.791571915149689;-0.169482126832008;574;-18
0.764164805412292;-0.163769245147705;577;95
0.68713790178299;-0.13568489253521;584;-10
0.620910346508026;-0.101558230817318;591;39
0.558325171470642;-0.0648491904139519;592;-33
0.563123226165771;-0.0372122302651405;582;0
0.591197848320007;-0.00514257745817304;576;-6
0.576822936534882;0.0385534428060055;561;0
0.563309013843536;0.0877642184495926;557;0
0.543411374092102;0.173397436738014;548;-4
0.523303031921387;0.26432603597641;567;13
0.510274350643158;0.337587267160416;565;-96
0.522768795490265;0.49935257434845;560;-9
0.547956705093384;0.666800320148468;531;-52
0.560039103031158;0.759092569351196;512;39
0.60129451751709;0.891500115394592;521;0
0.666414618492126;1.02409720420837;511;43
0.72550493478775;1.11989653110504;514;-44
0.780727922916412;1.21438133716583;507;-18
0.883557200431824;1.3586677312851;519;47
1.01310610771179;1.52460503578186;503;-3
1.11371326446533;1.6382098197937;486;33
1.20636773109436;1.73539865016937;486;0
1.34033906459808;1.8977382183075;486;26
1.4729505777359;2.06328296661377;496;0
1.56926429271698;2.1680908203125;495;-48
1.73186612129211;2.33294367790222;488;-1
1.90451061725616;2.50542235374451;478;0
2.02792096138;2.61799907684326;472;0
2.14616107940674;2.73013663291931;469;0
2.32290148735046;2.91296577453613;471;24
2.49825048446655;3.10102510452271;473;0
2.62044930458069;3.21845746040344;465;39
2.75998687744141;3.3259961605072;480;47
2.98670768737793;3.49841523170471;474;1
3.21134114265442;3.67858028411865;488;35
3.41563868522644;3.84252238273621;480;-57
3.71204137802124;4.07960844039917;485;16
3.96564340591431;4.27582454681396;499;0
4.13826084136963;4.40342807769775;491;0
4.32085180282593;4.55057191848755;493;48
4.58579111099243;4.76484346389771;508;-10
4.84011936187744;4.96460819244385;508;0
5.02617263793945;5.10592031478882;507;0
5.28893566131592;5.21624374389648;512;0
5.55021524429321;5.43106651306152;507;0
5.73386430740356;5.68302917480469;513;0
5.90430736541748;5.82657051086426;509;0
6.18439817428589;6.03178596496582;513;0
6.48823547363281;6.23036813735962;517;0
6.69073343276978;6.36072444915771;511;0
7.12117099761963;6.63185501098633;499;0
7.59643983840942;6.91918277740479;494;0
7.85292196273804;7.07386922836304;500;-12
8.08499908447266;7.20981121063232;495;0
8.44262599945068;7.40991020202637;504;0
8.79686832427979;7.61209726333618;509;0
9.0190315246582;7.74915361404419;508;21
9.25957679748535;7.89905643463135;504;2
9.62613010406494;8.12948226928711;495;14
9.98443698883057;8.35191822052002;503;0
10.2274370193481;8.49229526519775;493;-9
10.5783214569092;8.69333744049072;505;0
10.9533195495605;8.89903163909912;499;62
11.2243604660034;9.0412712097168;507;-52
11.5121631622314;9.18806743621826;495;47
11.9466562271118;9.40101909637451;493;-39
12.3527669906616;9.60810375213623;493;45
12.6240491867065;9.74940586090088;491;-59
12.8933582305908;9.89382934570313;495;-1
13.2908782958984;10.1209678649902;499;-34
13.7174654006958;10.3429832458496;507;92
14.025164604187;10.4872999191284;505;-24
14.317889213562;10.6334133148193;501;-6
14.7444763183594;10.8567810058594;502;36
15.2576217651367;11.1173944473267;497;94
15.6577920913696;11.3070344924927;498;-9
16.1436824798584;11.5235805511475;500;48
16.6165199279785;11.7352867126465;498;-96
16.9199562072754;11.8957061767578;499;24
17.2206115722656;12.0583610534668;488;4
17.7076625823975;12.3037796020508;499;-8
18.1975116729736;12.5424165725708;505;-19
18.5854034423828;12.7259473800659;502;-18
19.1407070159912;13.0006589889526;509;1
19.6286334991455;13.2358436584473;511;0
19.9609432220459;13.3916082382202;505;0
20.2888278961182;13.5471343994141;498;0
20.8237609863281;13.7776622772217;504;0
21.4333782196045;14.0366516113281;495;0
21.9898929595947;14.2801923751831;499;0
22.6754360198975;14.59312915802;500;0
23.2396774291992;14.8451461791992;500;0
23.631326675415;15.0022735595703;501;0
24.1975784301758;15.2334651947021;503;0
24.7728061676025;15.4670162200928;494;0
25.1563854217529;15.6208305358887;493;0
25.5245418548584;15.7702989578247;493;0
26.1089820861816;15.9955787658691;505;0
26.7018413543701;16.227201461792;504;0
27.0744361877441;16.3825016021729;505;0
27.4388198852539;16.5301628112793;507;0
28.0190696716309;16.7484474182129;503;0
28.644416809082;16.9858493804932;491;0
29.0651721954346;17.1557369232178;496;0
29.4413223266602;17.3066215515137;492;0
30.0532684326172;17.5254192352295;504;0
30.6769580841064;17.7512168884277;502;0
31.0830192565918;17.9074268341064;502;0
31.5000495910645;18.0609912872314;494;0
32.1917762756348;18.296501159668;498;0
32.8839111328125;18.5273704528809;492;0
33.3111724853516;18.6841564178467;490;0
33.9524002075195;18.9398040771484;505;0
34.5979690551758;19.1816940307617;511;0
35.0375671386719;19.3162784576416;503;0
35.4662590026855;19.4489288330078;498;0
36.2444152832031;19.6861324310303;503;0
37.0763397216797;19.9302139282227;497;0
37.5727233886719;20.0687789916992;498;0
38.0099220275879;20.1934566497803;501;0
38.7090148925781;20.387243270874;501;0
39.435718536377;20.5833587646484;503;0
39.9038772583008;20.7102355957031;500;0
40.6088371276855;20.9019985198975;496;0
41.3236618041992;21.0997619628906;496;0
41.8597793579102;21.2528076171875;491;0
42.3813095092773;21.4011363983154;500;0
43.1259994506836;21.5971012115479;503;0
44.1306190490723;21.862756729126;507;0
44.9158782958984;22.0796871185303;497;0
45.7363128662109;22.3150691986084;497;0
46.5621757507324;22.5568962097168;499;0
47.1177787780762;22.7191371917725;492;0
47.8661231994629;22.7775936126709;510;0
48.6381149291992;23.0421943664551;508;0
49.1785125732422;23.4106330871582;506;0
49.7126960754395;23.5855407714844;499;0
50.5248641967773;23.8382396697998;504;0
51.3489685058594;24.0779075622559;496;0
51.9019775390625;24.2136898040771;490;0
52.4747734069824;24.3455238342285;495;0
53.3867835998535;24.5426692962646;503;0
54.2978210449219;24.7285270690918;507;0
54.8804931640625;24.8302879333496;503;0
55.4243927001953;24.9199409484863;501;0
56.248908996582;25.0464496612549;492;0
57.1125717163086;25.1546955108643;498;0
57.8322677612305;25.2212104797363;497;0
58.844913482666;25.3161964416504;504;0
59.748405456543;25.3899345397949;510;0
60.3428382873535;25.4260215759277;499;0
60.9201583862305;25.4522686004639;504;0
61.812801361084;25.4819946289063;501;0
62.7257194519043;25.5090408325195;502;-79
63.3840370178223;25.5116539001465;492;83
64.0268020629883;25.5116100311279;499;-62
65.1046295166016;25.5110340118408;497;-1
66.2018051147461;25.5036334991455;502;0
66.828010559082;25.4884510040283;508;0
67.7600708007813;25.4468746185303;504;0
68.7273406982422;25.3907241821289;504;0
69.4160614013672;25.339204788208;502;0
70.0679626464844;25.2912406921387;504;0
71.0094909667969;25.2207088470459;506;0
71.9754104614258;25.1398239135742;511;0
72.6270446777344;25.0760326385498;499;-80
73.2801971435547;25.0063018798828;497;12
74.7356262207031;24.8334827423096;499;0
76.2307586669922;24.6511650085449;498;0
77.3177261352539;24.5042171478271;508;0
78.3719635009766;24.3561687469482;508;0
79.0700912475586;24.2514839172363;498;0
79.7625732421875;24.1431579589844;490;0
80.8058166503906;23.9748039245605;493;0
81.9000854492188;23.7930488586426;496;0
82.6428833007813;23.6654472351074;494;0
83.3855972290039;23.5362205505371;500;0
84.5400543212891;23.3239135742188;500;0
85.6877822875977;23.1043224334717;508;0
86.4404449462891;22.9566631317139;493;0
87.6018524169922;22.7208423614502;495;0
88.8059463500977;22.468900680542;491;0
89.6517486572266;22.2854995727539;493;0
90.4802093505859;22.1033458709717;499;0
91.6399688720703;21.8524856567383;502;0
92.7710647583008;21.6089725494385;504;0
93.482048034668;21.4551429748535;496;0
94.1656875610352;21.3069038391113;497;0
95.1940231323242;21.0810852050781;493;0
96.2621459960938;20.8412532806396;491;0
97.017822265625;20.6657447814941;494;0
97.7446594238281;20.4959297180176;498;-1
98.8876113891602;20.2263355255127;503;0
100.029273986816;19.9535789489746;499;0
100.758529663086;19.7752208709717;500;0
101.49178314209;19.5934352874756;502;-17
102.582084655762;19.3213138580322;500;63
103.691223144531;19.041524887085;499;-33
104.454788208008;18.8444271087646;498;0
105.228271484375;18.6410980224609;500;0
106.488479614258;18.3054389953613;500;0
107.757659912109;17.9657592773438;504;0
108.54736328125;17.7521953582764;504;0
109.970443725586;17.3579521179199;497;0
111.422286987305;16.9520587921143;496;0
112.2705078125;16.7134494781494;493;0
113.88826751709;16.2547664642334;497;0
115.595306396484;15.7639932632446;498;0
116.538757324219;15.4860982894897;501;87
117.88200378418;15.0882377624512;492;-53
119.260864257813;14.6764831542969;490;-1
120.185691833496;14.3973741531372;503;-6
121.090980529785;14.1227855682373;493;21
122.434638977051;13.7136135101318;502;-59
123.93970489502;13.2500762939453;509;-50
125.036842346191;12.9072723388672;508;-4
125.996673583984;12.6065721511841;502;23
127.510864257813;12.1282520294189;501;-51
129.070907592773;11.6323385238647;498;5
130.075576782227;11.3120079040527;487;-12
131.039001464844;11.0041313171387;502;18
132.527648925781;10.527247428894;499;-41
134.146209716797;10.0071630477905;503;32
135.248580932617;9.65196800231934;500;0
136.578369140625;9.22252941131592;499;0
137.820159912109;8.82043933868408;492;0
138.60563659668;8.56562614440918;494;0
139.354888916016;8.32218647003174;499;-62
140.456329345703;7.96395349502563;498;69
141.544662475586;7.60940456390381;500;-9
142.251556396484;7.37878751754761;504;45
142.92024230957;7.16040372848511;504;-21
143.885864257813;6.84447431564331;501;48
144.831085205078;6.53506278991699;485;0
145.446533203125;6.33353424072266;498;-47
146.040023803711;6.13885974884033;496;27
146.90202331543;5.85585880279541;506;-34
147.800994873047;5.56039237976074;503;28
148.37646484375;5.3710994720459;505;-25
149.148513793945;5.11697196960449;498;61
149.910034179688;4.86611413955688;499;-6
150.399322509766;4.70473051071167;496;6
150.862243652344;4.55209016799927;493;-69
151.555328369141;4.32356262207031;500;21
152.245162963867;4.09579420089722;505;-22
152.708129882813;3.94286465644836;507;21
153.607406616211;3.64570450782776;504;-63
154.448455810547;3.3675365447998;491;42
154.81721496582;3.24553608894348;502;-18
155.174362182617;3.12741184234619;500;-51
155.708084106445;2.9507622718811;500;25
156.237121582031;2.7755663394928;503;-18
156.564239501953;2.66723299026489;500;48
156.878540039063;2.56315588951111;499;-53
157.349166870117;2.40724062919617;496;13
157.806274414063;2.25576853752136;498;-57
158.131439208984;2.14795112609863;500;67
158.605743408203;1.99060869216919;506;-50
159.038711547852;1.84710645675659;502;-42
159.334762573242;1.7490177154541;499;22
159.609161376953;1.65801620483398;497;40
160.014434814453;1.52359807491302;495;-40
160.415710449219;1.39043009281158;497;-40
160.661605834961;1.30887365341187;487;-11
161.02067565918;1.18980634212494;496;10
161.407913208008;1.0613226890564;484;59
161.681411743164;0.970526218414307;478;-51
161.889923095703;0.901335775852203;479;13
162.196350097656;0.799659371376038;477;-5
162.502365112305;0.698092758655548;488;0
162.682235717773;0.638405025005341;479;52
162.941909790039;0.552233755588531;487;-26
163.20198059082;0.465890616178513;486;-26
163.367263793945;0.411022812128067;495;-31
163.523651123047;0.359126657247543;490;21
163.761169433594;0.280281394720078;488;21
163.996429443359;0.202238321304321;486;53
164.145248413086;0.15281555056572;496;-29
164.283599853516;0.106889598071575;495;47
164.487060546875;0.0393910631537437;505;-25
164.690002441406;-0.0279655233025551;501;21
164.820053100586;-0.0711322948336601;519;-68
164.942779541016;-0.111867435276508;507;-1
165.128860473633;-0.173650190234184;515;52
165.374847412109;-0.255403697490692;511;21
165.618896484375;-0.336396604776382;515;-1
165.79621887207;-0.39515021443367;522;-5
165.897018432617;-0.428605496883392;526;15
165.996887207031;-0.461749076843262;517;-19
166.14045715332;-0.509392976760864;526;47
166.289978027344;-0.559036016464233;524;-4
166.39013671875;-0.592276573181152;525;6
166.4755859375;-0.62062132358551;521;3
166.602798461914;-0.662864923477173;520;0
166.728271484375;-0.704512178897858;515;19
166.806793212891;-0.730555713176727;508;-48
166.883636474609;-0.756058096885681;510;33
166.997833251953;-0.793955981731415;531;0
167.108337402344;-0.830618441104889;536;-33
167.178344726563;-0.853868901729584;525;-1
167.245223999023;-0.876064658164978;535;61
167.344345092773;-0.908945381641388;516;-11
167.442443847656;-0.941503286361694;527;27
167.503890991211;-0.961889863014221;497;0
167.593933105469;-0.992573022842407;507;57
167.681640625;-1.02167153358459;511;-35
167.745361328125;-1.04206264019012;496;-2
167.807571411133;-1.06270480155945;490;0
167.885955810547;-1.08865571022034;507;80
167.96354675293;-1.11439883708954;493;-43
168.014572143555;-1.13133668899536;481;37
168.061889648438;-1.14703440666199;487;-30
168.134216308594;-1.17103397846222;490;-13
168.205581665039;-1.19471096992493;491;0
168.25114440918;-1.20982372760773;495;-49
168.295211791992;-1.22443914413452;494;51
168.356292724609;-1.24470722675323;477;-59
168.41650390625;-1.26468002796173;465;29
168.45475769043;-1.27737247943878;465;-24
168.51106262207;-1.2965692281723;468;39
168.566223144531;-1.31487023830414;477;-72
168.601226806641;-1.32597827911377;469;57
168.635101318359;-1.33721208572388;476;2
168.684310913086;-1.35352981090546;489;0
168.748031616211;-1.37466967105865;501;16
168.819076538086;-1.39863765239716;496;0
168.873092651367;-1.41656577587128;496;0
168.900344848633;-1.42519927024841;495;16
168.927963256836;-1.43435704708099;500;0
168.967971801758;-1.44763195514679;501;-7
169.006134033203;-1.46030056476593;511;0
169.031051635742;-1.46856236457825;509;0
169.05403137207;-1.47617447376251;508;0
169.088150024414;-1.4874941110611;511;-4
169.122619628906;-1.49892818927765;506;9
169.144454956055;-1.50616860389709;508;3
169.183319091797;-1.51906049251556;504;-24
169.221405029297;-1.53170108795166;514;0
169.240615844727;-1.53807306289673;511;0
169.25862121582;-1.5440411567688;502;0
169.284896850586;-1.55275011062622;503;6
169.311660766602;-1.56163370609283;496;0
169.328979492188;-1.56737232208252;495;0
169.344680786133;-1.57258117198944;499;0
169.367660522461;-1.58020341396332;500;0
169.390716552734;-1.58785283565521;505;0
169.40576171875;-1.59283769130707;500;0
169.419845581055;-1.5975114107132;499;0
169.440475463867;-1.60435259342194;499;0
169.461120605469;-1.61120474338531;499;0
169.474090576172;-1.61550164222717;498;0
169.486389160156;-1.61958014965057;501;0
169.505615234375;-1.6259571313858;500;0
169.524673461914;-1.63227951526642;501;0
169.535903930664;-1.63600313663483;493;0
169.552642822266;-1.64155554771423;499;0
169.569122314453;-1.6470205783844;492;0
169.579467773438;-1.65045475959778;492;0
169.589614868164;-1.6538177728653;500;0
169.604446411133;-1.65873682498932;502;0
169.618988037109;-1.66355764865875;500;0
169.628997802734;-1.66687715053558;501;0
169.638610839844;-1.67006540298462;497;0
169.651473999023;-1.67432940006256;499;0
169.664260864258;-1.67857682704926;494;0
169.677261352539;-1.68288433551788;503;0
169.69499206543;-1.6887640953064;502;0
169.707626342773;-1.69295692443848;499;0
169.714645385742;-1.69528806209564;503;0
169.724899291992;-1.69868385791779;497;0
169.735122680664;-1.70207405090332;491;0
169.741561889648;-1.70421409606934;501;0
169.747634887695;-1.70622313022614;497;0
169.756546020508;-1.70917665958405;506;0
169.765426635742;-1.71212458610535;500;0
169.771148681641;-1.71402442455292;503;0
169.776809692383;-1.71589684486389;502;0
169.785095214844;-1.71864295005798;495;0
169.792892456055;-1.72123074531555;495;17
169.797866821289;-1.72288465499878;499;3
169.802795410156;-1.72451710700989;497;-93
169.809921264648;-1.72687554359436;499;43
169.817443847656;-1.72937572002411;512;-45
169.822601318359;-1.7310791015625;499;66
169.829360961914;-1.73332273960114;500;-21
169.835830688477;-1.73547375202179;493;2
169.839874267578;-1.73681116104126;494;0
169.843704223633;-1.73808312416077;494;0
169.850326538086;-1.7402777671814;499;0
169.856964111328;-1.74247765541077;510;0
169.860580444336;-1.74367868900299;503;-42
169.865585327148;-1.74533832073212;500;11
169.870452880859;-1.74694871902466;496;70
169.87353515625;-1.74797511100769;498;2
169.876541137695;-1.74897396564484;504;-69
169.880966186523;-1.75043702125549;502;33
169.885345458984;-1.75188910961151;500;-26
169.888198852539;-1.75283360481262;507;2
169.890869140625;-1.75372326374054;501;0
169.894912719727;-1.75506627559662;498;0
169.898986816406;-1.75641477108002;497;0
169.901504516602;-1.75724983215332;499;27
169.903839111328;-1.75802505016327;503;0
169.907287597656;-1.75916600227356;506;-20
169.911361694336;-1.7605197429657;504;0
169.914703369141;-1.76162803173065;492;-55
169.918548583984;-1.76289987564087;489;4
169.921768188477;-1.76396441459656;489;0
169.923645019531;-1.76459217071533;503;-14
169.926422119141;-1.76550936698914;499;51
169.929122924805;-1.76641011238098;506;39
169.930862426758;-1.76698327064514;497;41
169.932540893555;-1.76754009723663;501;-46
169.934951782227;-1.76833713054657;496;-1
169.937347412109;-1.76913416385651;496;2
169.938873291016;-1.76963627338409;490;-35
169.940338134766;-1.77012765407562;507;8
169.942474365234;-1.770831823349;497;3
169.944595336914;-1.77154147624969;502;0
169.945983886719;-1.7720000743866;503;0
169.947265625;-1.77242577075958;496;18
169.949249267578;-1.77308082580566;491;-42
169.951217651367;-1.77373600006104;496;0
169.952407836914;-1.77412903308868;487;0
169.953506469727;-1.77448928356171;507;0
169.955169677734;-1.7750461101532;510;0
169.956802368164;-1.77558648586273;503;0
169.958129882813;-1.77602326869965;500;-14
169.959991455078;-1.7766455411911;499;0
169.961547851563;-1.77716422080994;499;0
169.962539672852;-1.7774863243103;492;0
169.963943481445;-1.77795577049255;507;0
169.965240478516;-1.77838706970215;504;0
169.966079711914;-1.77865993976593;501;0
169.966888427734;-1.778932929039;499;89
169.968063354492;-1.77932035923004;495;-35
169.96923828125;-1.77970802783966;492;3
169.970016479492;-1.77996456623077;500;-9
169.970733642578;-1.78020465373993;499;41
169.971786499023;-1.78055417537689;505;-75
169.972808837891;-1.78089261054993;503;53
169.97346496582;-1.78111100196838;499;-8
169.97412109375;-1.78132939338684;504;11
169.975067138672;-1.78164041042328;497;-75
169.975967407227;-1.78194606304169;493;51
169.97673034668;-1.78219723701477;496;-23
169.978103637695;-1.78265035152435;506;-27
```